# Proper Mutex usage / Good coding style?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex, multiprocessing

Within the following code, the producer periodically_fill_page_queue might add a page to the queue that is currently being consumed (read: in the consumer before the status `being_processed` is set).

```
class Example

  def initialize
    @threads      = ThreadGroup.new
    @page_queue   = Queue.new
    Thread.abort_on_exception = true
  end

  def start
    periodically_fill_page_queue
    periodically_process_page_queue
  end

  def periodically_fill_page_queue
    @threads.add(Thread.new do
      loop do
        if @page_queue.empty?
          Page.with_state(:waiting).each do |p|
            p.queued!
            @page_queue << f
          end
        end
        sleep 2
      end
    end)
  end

  def periodically_process_page_queue
    loop do
      until file = @page_queue.pop
        sleep 2
      end
      page.being_processed
      process(page)
    end
  end

  def process(page)
    sleep 120
    page.processed
  end

end


class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

  state_machine :state, :initial => :waiting do

    event :queued do
      transition :waiting => :queued
    end

    event :being_processed do
      transition :queued => :being_processed
    end

    event :processed do
      transition :being_processed => :processed
    end

  end

end
```

To avoid this, i'd use a Mutex object:

```
def initialize
  ...
  @mutex = Mutex.new
end

def periodically_process_page_queue
  loop do
    until file = @page_queue.pop
      sleep 2
    end
    @mutex.synchronize { page.being_processed }
    process(page)
  end
end
```

Is this "good" coding style, or are there any more elegant approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even compile, thanks to `until file = @page_queue.pop)`. Please put a bit of effort into your questions.

Comment: I have put a sample program showing filling and processing queues using Threads in Ruby in [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392028/windows-ruby-background-processing).

Comment: Additionally, what's a `Page`? Is that a class that you're using but haven't defined in this code sample?

Comment: Sorry, this was meant to be an abstracted example. I've made some changes, hope it gets a bit clearer now. The question is basically if the Queue / Mutex approach is a good way to go...

Answer (score 1):

Not with this design. Some alternative designs might do one of the below, but naturally have their own can of worms.

### "Fork"

For each job you start a new thread or process, giving it the job

### Delegation

Delegate the task to a queue in each thread. Each thread pulls from its own unique queue.

### Stride

You have a circular buffer and each thread checks at a different interval. E.G. `Num_threads + thread.id`
This probably isn't for your situation.

### Range

A thread is responsible for a range of jobs. `num_threads * thread.id`
This probably isn't for your situation.