# Two loops simultaneously?

Tags: ruby

How would I run two `loop do ... end` simultaneously in Ruby? One would be for CLI interface and the other would be for background processing.

Comment: Whether to use threads or fibers depends on whether you want one loop to interact with the other at a particular timing. If yes, then use `Fiber`. If you simply want to start the second loop while the other loop is taking time, then use `Thread` (You can still let one thread wait until the other thread finishes). So you need to specify your needs in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want two [threads](http://apidock.com/ruby/Thread).

Comment: I have looked at threads and fibers and don't fully understand them.. Any examples?

Comment: @c00lryguy `Thread.new{ loop{ ... } }` [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392028/windows-ruby-background-processing/4392590#4392590) of mine might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use yield to create [co-routines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine)

Generators like Ruby's can be 'abused' to create coroutines. I don't speak Ruby but I could outline the concept in C# or Python.

It also appears like [something was added in Ruby 1.9 to make this easier](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/08/ruby-1-9-fibers)

Cheers

Comment: Yes. Fiber is for this purpose.

Comment: An example of Fibers is [here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/08/ruby-1-9-fibers)